# How to remove the checked item in the listivew using jquery?

Tags: jquery, listview, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I'm dynamcially creating a listview for storing the data. When I click on the button the the listview is appended with checkboxes. When I'm selecting the individual checkbox of items in the listview that particular list item has to be deleted from the listview. But when I'm trying to delete the particular item is not deleting.

```
$('#add #input[name="check"]:checkbox').change(function () {
    var chkLength = $('input[name="check"]:checkbox').length;
    var chkdLength = $('input[name="check"]:checkbox:checked').length;
    if (chkLength == chkdLength) {
        $('#select').attr('checked', true);
        //$('#empty').on('click', function() {
        $('#add input[name="check"]:checkbox:checked').on('click', function () {
            $('#empty').on('click', function () {
                localStorage.removeItem($(this).attr('url'));
                $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
            });
        });
    } else {
        $('#select').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

**UPDATED:**

I'm creating the listview and checkbox's everthing dynamic.

```
$('#edit').live('click', function () {
    fromGetStorage();
});

function fromGetStorage() {

    $("#favoritesList").empty();
    $(".ui-listview-filter").remove();
    $("#favoritesList").append('<input type="checkbox" name="all" id="select" />Select all</br>');
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        var url = localStorage.key(i);
        var demo = localStorage.getItem(url);
        $("#favoritesList").append('<li id="add"><div><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check">&nbsp;<a href="' + url + '" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">' + demo + '</a></div></li>').attr('url', url);
        $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
    }

    $("#select").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('#select').change(function () {
        if ($("#select").is(':checked')) {
            $("#add #check").prop("checked", true);
            $('#empty').on('click', function () {
                localStorage.clear();
                $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
            });
        } else {
            $("#add #check").prop("checked", false);
        }
    });
    $("#add #check").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('#add #input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var chkLength = $('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
        var chkdLength = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        var item = $(this);
        var content = $(item).text();
        if (chkLength == chkdLength) {
            $('#select').attr('checked', true);
            if (item.is(':checked')) {
                $("#delete").click(function () {
                    $('#' + content).remove();
                    $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
                });
            }

        } else {
            $('#select').attr('checked', false);
        }
    });


}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: please show your html and check reference of "this" inside onclick function

Comment: @AlexKneller i'm creating listivew and checkbox dynamcially anyway i updated with my code.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

This bit of code in your function :

```
$("#delete").click(function () {
    $('#' + content).remove();
    $("#favoritesList").listview('refresh');
});
```

is not necessary. (I think). Your code is extremely unclear abt what its trying to achieve. **Unless you explain what you are trying to achieve with a fiddle at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), it might be very difficult to solve this**. But for starters, you might want to do this :

```
 $('#add #input[type="checkbox"]').change(function () {
        var chkLength = $('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
        var chkdLength = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
        var item = $(this);
        var content = $(item).text();
        if (chkLength === chkdLength) {
            $('#select').attr('checked', true);
            if (item.is(':checked')) {
                item.closest("li").remove(); //remove delete click initialisation
            }

        } else {
            $('#select').attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

To format your code, use one of the below methods to create the listview. If you ask me thats where the problem lies.

### The easy way - Creation of checkbox list using control group

First of all, using listview to create checkbox list is plain wrong. You must use control group for this instead of listview. Reason is because adapting the listview to house the `checkbox` will invlove lot of CSS work. The control group provides more functionality and is much more cleaner when it handles events.

1. Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/V8jda/8/
2. A more styled up demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/V8jda/

### The hard way - Creation of checkbox list using listview

If you're still adamant on using listview, here's an example. You can add a class called `container` to the `li` and style it like this :

```
.container {
    padding : 0 !important;
    border-width : 0 !important;
}
.container label {
    margin : 0;
}
```

Then, the content in your `<li/>` must look like this :

```
<li class="container">
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-0a" id="checkbox-0a" data-theme="c">
   <label data-corners="false" for="checkbox-0a">Sweet Child 'O Mine </label> 
</li>
```

You have to fill this template with your array from your `localStorage`. Try to make your listview in `pageinit` event of your parent page like this :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mypage", function () {
    var $page = $(this);
    //assuming this comes from localStorage
    var songs = ["Sweet Child 'O Mine", "Summer of '69", "Smoke in the Water", "Enter Sandman", "I thought I've seen everything"];

    //array of li - empty
    var li = [];

    $.each(songs, function (i, song) {
        //the variable you'll be using for input - label relationship
        var idForName = "checkbox-" + i + "a";
        //create cbox HTML
        var cbox = '<li class="container"><input type="checkbox" name="' + idForName + '" id="' + idForName + '" data-theme="c"/><label data-corners="false" for="' + idForName + '" >' + songs[i] + ' </label> </fieldset></li>';
        //add it to li[] array
        li.push(cbox);
    });
    //cache ul for later use
    var $ul = $("#songlist");
    //append the li to ul
    $ul.html(li)
    //refresh listview
    $ul.listview("refresh");
    //refresh the checkbox etc
    $ul.trigger("create");
});
```

and the change event must look like this (this must also be in the pageinit event)

```
//change event on input:checked (will fire only when check box is checked)
$ul.on("change", "input[type=checkbox]:checked", function () {
   //call our slideRight function on .container class
   $(this).closest("li").remove();
   //refresh 
   $ul.listview("refresh").trigger("create");
});
```

1. Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/SYA3y/6/
2. A more styled up demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/SYA3y/

Comment: i tried but where i did the mistake i'm not getting can you please implement this in my code once Thanks in Advance.

Comment: yes sure.. but can make a fiddle for your problem? just use my static array for localStorage data.

Comment: @user2384323 any progress on the fiddle?

Comment: can you make a fiddle for this please? at jsfiddle.net

Comment: yes sure but making a fiddle for this i need to load all the files, and xml's everything...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34294/discussion-between-hungerpain-and-user2384323)